# why occur this query "No database selected"

Tags: mariadb

mariadb version = 10.0.17-MariaDB-log

I am not in a position to choose a database at this time.

```
use dbname; --->> DO NOT USE THIS (if I use this query, it works well)

UPDATE dbname.t_co_sec_grade A INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sec_id
         , upper_sec_id
          , sec_depth
          , sec_name_kr
          , IF(upper_sec_id = '111', '004', upper_sec_id) AS modify_upper_sec_id
          , sec_depth - 1 AS modify_sec_depth
      FROM dbname.t_co_sec_grade ABC INNER JOIN (SELECT @pv := '111') AS .initialisation
      WHERE find_in_set(upper_sec_id, @pv) > 0
        AND @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', sec_id)
) B ON A.sec_id = B.sec_id
SET A.upper_sec_id = B.modify_upper_sec_id, A.sec_depth = B.modify_sec_depth;
```

Why do I get "No database selected"?

Comment: Was this run from the commandline tool "mysql"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with earlier MariaDB/MySQL version caused by the `INNER JOIN (SELECT @pv := '111')`. You can update to the latest version which has this issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not include the "use dbname;" line you will indeed run into an issue with your update.

If you are attempting to write the query without the use, you can use a fully qualified line.

```
UPDATE [dbname].[schema].[table]
```

Comment: what is the [schema]?

Comment: The syntax in question is for SQL Server / Sybase. In MySQL the syntax is `dbname.table`. In MySQL schema == database.